# Where did the convention of two-sentence episode titles in Shonen series originate?

Tags: tropes

I heard a joke on a Podcast the other day that said Shonen Anime tend to have episode titles that are two sentences long. I noticed the case with both *Dragon Ball Super* and *Fist of the North Star*.

What series set this trend, and why does it seem so prevalent?

Comment: Related: [why-do-light-novels-and-manga-have-long-titles](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/56511/1458)